# Are Abraham Ibn Ezra and Moshe Ibn Ezra related?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, song-poetry, avraham-ibn-ezra

Are these two figures of Jew tradition related, and if so, can anyone point me to any encyclopedia articles which deal with this question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ibn_Ezra

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/biography/Moses-ben-Jacob-ha-Sallah-ibn-Ezra "Known in Arabic as Abū Hārūn Mūsā, he belonged to a prominent Hispano-Hebrew family (his three brothers were eminent scholars) and was related to the poet and biblical interpreter Abraham ibn Ezra."

Comment: wikipedia says that they were related but gives no details. The Jewish encyclopedia says the same. An article on JSTOR says that they were not related.

Comment: Which article please?

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1455672?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Thanks, found it on page 536. Does anyone know of a more detailed explanation other than "they are not related"?